# Using react-native-maps to Change pinColor of MapView.Marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

The color of `MapView.Marker` does not seem to change from the default red color even after assigning a color to `pinColor`.

Is something wrong?

```
{ this.state.markers.map(marker => {
    return (
        <MapView.Marker 
            coordinate={{latitude: marker.latitude, longitude: marker.longitude}}
            key={marker.key}
            pinColor='#000000'
        />
    )
})}
```

**Screen cap from Android Emulator**

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed the curly braces. Everything else is fine and it will work or better define the color as const and pass that like this.

const pinColor = '#000000';

and then pass it like..

pinColor = {pinColor}

Answer (score 9):

Allowed colors for Marker are: red, tomato, orange, yellow, green,  gold, wheat, linen, tan, blue, aqua, teal, violet, purple, indigo, turquoise, navy and plum.

Like:

```js
<MapView.Marker
    pinColor={'green'}
/>
```